# How to use api.events.staking.Rewarded.is to get nominator reward?

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, rewards

How to use api.events.staking.Rewarded.is to get reward?
Like this:

```
let event:IEventLike={
  index:9281,
  method:"staking",
  section:"rewarded",
};
const nominatorReward = api.events.staking.Rewarded.is(event)
console.log(nominatorReward)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the block hash when the event was triggered and the index number of the event you can query all the events and parse it to find your specific event, and check the data in it.

See an example:

```
const blockHash = "0xaef9fe68122e5659638f426077e45dee30dc7d62f9627b3a0896fa3392ff263c";
const eventNumber = 547;
const at = await api.at(blockHash);
const events = await at.query.system.events(); 
console.log(events[eventNumber].event.data.toHuman());
```

The result of the console log is:

```
[ '15SpxEyZszSGKsYDqCSDgHr4CHUgx79qNwd4GW8T5AZQGCCc', '588,174,178' ]
```

Which is the stash account and the amount rewarded.

This code is to retrieve the information of an Event used as an example that you can find in [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/12343544-3?event=12343544-547)

Comment: I want to get nominator reward by nominator address not by block hash ? how to do?

Comment: If you don't know the blockHash you can query the events of all blocks and filter with the nominator address. See how to query all events: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/system-events

Comment: Is there any way to get nominator reward from nominator address during selected era?
I think browsing events is too time consuming.

Comment: Hello @AlexBean I can get stash account and reward amount from event. How can I get validator account address and era number? So, this reward is which era's reward and which validator rewarded.

Comment: Check this to get the era: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other/#map-keys--entries

Comment: For a different question, I recommend you to open a new Question in the forum instead of asking in the comments. Would benefit people from the community too

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/get-era-and-validator-address-from-rewarded-event. I am not sure how to get era from above comment. Could you check new question and answer there @AlexBean?