# Get era and validator address from Rewarded event

Tags: validator, era, payouts

I have Staking Rewarded event.

I can get stash address and reward amount from it.

[How to use api.events.staking.Rewarded.is to get nominator reward?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5172/how-to-use-api-events-staking-rewarded-is-to-get-nominator-reward)

How can I get validator address and era from event?

So, I can get know which validator did payout for which era.

Comment: What have you tried? How did you *get the event*? What technology are you coding in? E.g. What do you get when you `console.debug(event.toJSON())`.

Comment: Using PolkadotJS, it says in the question is using this code example to get the event: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5181/2762

Comment: I got events from ```api.query.system.events()``` and when I log event, ```{"phase":{"applyExtrinsic":2},"event":{"index":"0x0601","data":["HALCY1MaPw6e2TeBjFg8DuABy9aWef6udFPdFnHiwXLkK2U",874758234]},"topics":[]}```.
There are two things in data, one is stash address, the other one is reward amount.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the era of that event because you have the block hash where that event occurs:

```
const at = await api.at(blockHash);
const era = await at.query.staking.activeEra();
console.log(era.toHuman());
```

If you want the set of validators in that moment:

```
const validators = await at.query.session.validators();
console.log(validators.toHuman());
```

If you want to see the list of the rewards for that eras:

```
const erasValidatorReward = await api.query.staking.erasRewardPoints(numberOfEra);
console.log(erasValidatorReward.toHuman());
```

Comment: I know in which era event is produced. What I want to know is, which era's reward is triggered. According to my example, this reward event is produced in 4576. And 4575 era's reward is given to nominator. I want to get this 4575 value from event.

Comment: Would you like to join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133964/substrate-and-polkadot? @alexbean

Comment: Sorry, not sure I get it. In your example you have the era event 4576 and you want to get the 4575 era's reward ?

Comment: My example Rewarded event was created in Era 4576. And this is 4575 era's reward. 
So, 4575 era's reward is paid to nominator in 4576 era. https://kusama.subscan.io/reward?address=HALCY1MaPw6e2TeBjFg8DuABy9aWef6udFPdFnHiwXLkK2U&page=2&role=account. Please check top row. Era shows 4575, and event ID is 15836105-348. This block number is created in 4576,